# How to upgrade AdoptOpenJDK8 and Java11 with Homebrew

Tags: homebrew, java-11, jenv, adoptopenjdk

I have searched a little bit, but im a little bit confused.

I have installed Java8 and Java11 by homebrew. Java8 is installed with `adoptopenjdk/openjdk` tap and Java11 is from `homebrew/cask` tap. When i see the version for AdoptOpenJDK i see this version:

`openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_212-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)` but on Oracle i see that the build number is 33, and i have `b03`. How to update the version with homebrew?

When i switch to Java11 by using `Jenv` and get version on terminal i get:
`openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9, mixed mode)`

On oracle i see that the version is `11.0.3`, how to update this? Or cant i do that by homebrew? Or is it any other better solutions to install java and switch between versions?

Thank for all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least the Java 11 version is not available. Here is how to check

1. Update brew `brew update`
2. Search for java casks `brew search java`
3. See info for java11 cask `brew cask info java11`

```
$ brew cask info java11
java11: 11.0.2,9
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/blob/master/Casks/java11.rb
==> Name
OpenJDK Java Development Kit
==> Artifacts
jdk-11.0.2.jdk -> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk (Generic Artifact)
```

Do the same for your Java 8 version. If a newer version is available upgrade your package with `brew cask upgrade java11`

Comment: I run the steps you mentioned but I get the following error when I run `brew cask info java11`, `Error: Cask 'java11' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.`. Have you came across this issue before? Thanks.

Comment: Never-mind. That's because I didn't have AdoptOpenJDK8 but instead, I had Oracle JDK8. Thanks.

Comment: `brew cask upgrade adoptopenjdk11`
In my case this works